# Isolate external components(packages) styling - React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles, dropzone

Disclaimer: I have checked examples where developer isolate their own components, but I am not sure that this approach is applicable for my case.

Hello,
I am using `@mui` package for the UI, and [dropzone](https://yuvaleros.github.io/material-ui-dropzone/) library for the files upload, which  uses `@material-ui` for the styles. The is that dropzone library seems to be overriding styles for `@mui` package elements like buttons. My question is - is there any way to isolate styles of those packages?

Code:

```
<Button className="upload-media-button" variant="contained" onClick={() => {setFileObjects([])}}>
   Btn
</Button> //this btn is from @mui
<div className="page-content">
    <DropzoneAreaBase
        fileObjects={fileObjects}
        acceptedFiles={['image/*']}
        dropzoneText={t('labels.Drag_n_drop')}
        onAdd={handleAdd}
        maxFileSize={200000000}
        filesLimit={1000}
        onDelete={handleDelete}
        getPreviewIcon={handlePreviewIcon}
    />
</div>
```

The result I am getting:

[image]

Could someone help me or point in direction where I can find an answer?